# In a Datagrid: How to display change in cell B after changing value in cell A

Tags: .net, xaml, datagrid, winui-3, winui

I have a winui3 project using the `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid`.
I have an `ObservableCollection<ExampleClass>` that I bind to a `DataGrid`.
The relevant variables of the ExampleClass are: `Amount int, Price int, TotalPrice int`.
I added an event to my datagrid, `CellEditEnded`, which updates the `TotalPrice` to `Amount * Price`.
After the user changes `Amount` or `Price` in the datagrid at runtime, but the following problem is still there with any kind of change to the value of `TotalPrice`.
Price is == 10 at the start of the app. When the user changes Amount to let's say 2, the Totalprice Cell of that ExampleClass instance still shows 0 (0 amount * 10 price). I have checked and the TotalPrice value has correctly changed in the Observablecollection. The problem is that the DataGrid won't show the change. When I reload the page, the change is finally made correctly. Alternatively when the user starts editing the TotalPrice cell, the correct value suddenly shows up and stays in the cell. Funny also when I try to change the totalprice value manually, it always goes back to the correct value.

With this problem the user, after editing amount or price, always has to start editing all the outdated totalprice cells to see the correct value. OR he reloads the page to see all correct values.

The DataGrid seems not to update cell B (TotalPrice) when cell A (Amount or Price) is changed.

Amount = Anzahl, Price = Preis

```xml
<controls:DataGrid 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.kgr.Tabelle1, Mode=OneWay}"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="0"
    CellEditEnded="DataGrid_CellEditEnded>
    <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundColor" Color="Transparent" />
    </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Bereich" />
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Anzahl}" Header="Fläche in m^2" />
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Preis}" Header="€ pro m^2" />
        <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TotalPreis}" Header="Gesamt"/>
        <!-- IsReadOnly="True" -->
    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

I focused on the xaml file because the datasource is working all well.
There I tried alternatives to the celleditevent, Binding Modes in the itemsource, other xaml properties in the: itemsource, datagrid itself, totalprice column, totalprice binding property etc etc.
many of these properties had promising names (like `UpdateSourceTrigger`, Bindmode = twoway), but I tried alot of them and none seem to work.
I am probably missing something but the mediocre documentation and young age of winui3 doesn't help,
and I can't imagine that this feature wouldn't exist in a UI framework of Microsoft.

WPF devs use propertychanged, I looked for something with that name and found its a property of binding inside Datagridtextcolumn or a property inside itemsource, but the documentation is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.controls.datagridboundcolumn.binding?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0#communitytoolkit-winui-ui-controls-datagridboundcolumn-binding

Even a temporary inelegant fix will do, like reloading the datagrid, I just need something.

Hoping for some help.

Comment: Can you share xaml code around your ``DataGrid``? [Here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c) you can see how to post code in StackOverflow. By the way, I prefer the third way in the link.

Comment: just did add the xaml. I got rid of all the properties i tried, because they just didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that you are not implementing `INotifyPropertyChange` on your properties.

This is a sample code the uses the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) NuGet package the will generate code that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you.

**Item.cs**

```cs
public partial class Item : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string name = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Total))]
    private int price;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Total))]
    private int quantity;

    public int Total => Price * Quantity;
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Item> items = new();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "A", Price = 100, Quantity = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "B", Price = 200, Quantity = 2 });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "C", Price = 300, Quantity = 3 });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "D", Price = 400, Quantity = 4 });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "E", Price = 500, Quantity = 5 });
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="DataGridExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:DataGridExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                    Header="Name"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Price}"
                    Header="Price" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Quantity}"
                    Header="Quantity" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding Total}"
                    Header="Total"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: adding [UbservableProperty] gives me the error of the sourcegenerator: cs0101 The namespace xz.Models.Items already has a definition for Item (using your names). Also NotifyPropertyChangedFor is not found, i can only use AlsoNotifyChangeFor or INotifyPropertyChanged from the communitytoolkit

Comment: Did you install the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** NuGet package? If so, can you downgrade it to v8.0? not the latest v8.2.

Comment: didnt know i had to install it. following your code example i got it to work. thank you so much Andrew.